Using a regular expression in Blazor routing
I want to use regular expressions inside the Blazor route. I know that in the .Net 8 version of Blazer Web App - this is possible, because I created a template for this app and regular expressions worked there. In the main application I was using Blazer Web Assembly, which I upgraded to WebApp according to Microsoft documentation. But these actions did not work and when I use regular expressions in the route I get this error:
Unhandled exception rendering component: The constraint entry 'doc' - 'regex((.*)(?:\/details)$)' on the route '/{{*doc:regex((.*)(?:\/details)$)}' could not be resolved by the constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver'. 
System.InvalidOperationException: The constraint entry 'doc' - 'regex((.*)(?:\/details)$)' on the route '/{{*doc:regex((.*)(?:\/details)$)})}' could not be resolved by the constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver'.

The route looks like this:
@attribute [Route(@“/{{*doc:regex((.*)(?:\/details)$)$)}”)]]   
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly
[Parameter] public string doc { get; set; }

Again, this route works in the Blazor template.
Please tell me where I made a mistake?
Program.cs code:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseException
    Handler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly);
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


Hi @Артём Цибульский, it seems you do not migrate successfully. As you said, it you create a new Blazor Server app, it can work fine. Maybe you need share how do you migrate the project.

Hi, @Rena, I am migrating clearly according to the instructions from Web Assembly to WebApp:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio
Creating the App.Razor file in .Server and give him the code index.html , after which I delete index.html . Renaming App.razor to Routes.razor, adding to .csproj .Client 2 lines:
true
Default
and so on... I didn't miss a single point in the instructions.
